# Finding the Sum of divisors of a big factorial number?

Tags: math, factorial

I am trying to come up with an efficient way to list all divisors of a big factorial. Let's say 1000!. It is quite impossible with brute force. Is there an efficient approach?
I need to process them i.e. to find their sum for a programming challenge.

Comment: If you just want the prime factorisation, that's easy. If you want all distinct combinations of the prime factors (which is what "all divisors" suggests), then I *think* there are about 10**106 of them. What do you propose doing with them?

Comment: AakashM is right, [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sigma_0%281000!%29) is the number of divisors of 1000!, so obviously listing them all is not possible.

Comment: I need to process them i.e. to find their sum for a programming challenge.

Comment: In that case, it may help to tell you that while finding all divisors and adding them together *works* as a method of finding the sum of all divisors, there is a far quicker and easier method. You can find details [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html) (equation 14), but be warned that the number you seek is [very large](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sigma_1%281000!%29)

Comment: yeah I know I will use Python :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find the prime factorisation of each number <= 1000. I would store this as a dictionary of prime -> power. E.g. for a single number like 24 `{2: 3, 3: 1}` because 24 is `2**3 * 3**1`.
2. Find the prime factorisation of `1000!`. This is the combination of the dictionaries of numbers <= 1000 combined by summing all the values for each of the keys (the primes).
3. You can then use [equation 14 on this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html) as @AakashM already said.

Comment: What would be the approach if N which is 1000 in this case , becomes as large as 10E8 ?

Comment: I think the approach would be exactly the same, it would just take longer! Have you tried that? What problem are you finding?

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps for an efficient solution:

1. n! can be represented as :- n! = (a1^p1)  (a2^p2)x...(ak^pk).

   where ak is the prime divisor lesser than n and pk is the highest power
   which can divide n!.
2. Through sieve find the prime number and the highest power can be
   easily find out by :

   ```
   countofpower =  [n/a] + [n/a^2] + [n/a^3] +...... or   `  while (n)
   {
     n/ = a;
     ans += n
   }
   ```
3. Count Of Factors = `(ans1 +1)*(ans2 +1)*....(ansk +1)`
4. After calculating this last step is the sum :

   ```
   SUM = product of all (pow(ak,pk+1)-1)/(ak-1);
   ex = 4! 
   4! = 2^3 * 3^1;
   count of factors = (3+1)*(1+1) = 8 (1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24)
   sum = ( 1 + 2 + 4 + 8)*(1 + 3) = 60.
   ```